# Metric space question

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

Let (M,p) be a metric space and suppose that ${x_n}$ is a sequence in (M,p) so that $x_n -> x$ and $x_n->y$. prove x=y

Let $E>0$. then,

$p(x_n,x)->0$

$lim$ $n->inf$

$p(x_n,y)->0$

$lim$ $n->inf$

Suppose $p(x,y)=abs(x-y)$

$abs(x_n-x)<E$ and $abs(x_n-y)<E$

Thus, x=y. is this correct?

Comment: You mean $x_n\to y$ right?

Comment: yep, that was a typo. fixed now.

Comment: @permafrst What definition are you familiar with for convergence? If it involves $\epsilon$ you should follow Dimitris solution. Once again as I wrote on your previous post you should use arbitrary metrics, do not define them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $ε>0$ , then there is a $n_1\in \Bbb N$:$p(x_n,x)<ε/2$ for every $n\geq n_1$

Also  there is a $n_2\in \Bbb N$:$p(x_n,y)<ε/2$ for every $n\geq n_2$

Let $k=max(n_1,n_2)$. Then we have that $p(x,y)\leq p(x_n,x) +p(x_n,y)<ε/2+ε/2=ε$ for every $n\geq k$ and thus $x=y$

Comment: I have recently learned that it is advisable to give just hints to homework questions. just so you know that too :D your answer is of course really good and clear.

Comment: right, this is what the other commenter recommended i attempt. thank you for the clear solution!

Comment: I understood what he was trying to say and i just helped him to see how to write it down more clear,btw nice eyes!:P

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track; anyway, you need to be careful since $|\cdot|$ is something that makes sense if your space is the real line (and friends), while the result is true in general.

The following is an hint that can lead you to a rigorous proof: *use the triangle inequality!*

Moreover, if you know some basic topology, you may probably want to show that every metric space is Hausdorff (and hence, if it exists, the limit is unique).

Comment: ah so like p(x_n,x) <= p(x_n, y) + p(y, x)..etc?

Comment: not exactly. look, you want $x = y$, which happens if and only if $p(x,y) = 0$. so it is reasonable to start with $p(x,y)$, being the quantity you want to estimate. :)